# Writing a generated list to entire column in google sheets with python

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I have been experimenting with the google sheets API and python. However, I am rather new to all of this. My idea was to create a list with values from 1 to 10 which then are written to the spreadsheet in for example column A. How would I approach this issue?  Thank you for help and time!

```
import gspread

n = []

gc = gspread.service_account(filename='/Users/steph/Documents/Elab SOPs/API Test/elabtest.json')

sh = gc.open("Test")

wks = gc.open("Test").sheet1

for i in range(1,11):
    n = i
    print (n)

wks.update('A',n)
print(sh.sheet1.get('A'))
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your current issue?

Comment: Do not apologize, your English is good. I want to generate an array or list of values in python which is then updated into google sheets. The idea is that each value in the array is displayed in its own cell in for example column A.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Because I noticed that you misunderstood my comment. I think that your replying is your goal. I asked about the current issue of your script. I think that I can think of the solution by correctly understanding your current issue. How about this? If you cannot understand my English, please tell me.